# Por qué no funciona mi código para hallar números primos por el método de la Criba de Eratóstenes?

Tags: java, boolean

He escrito el método para hallar los números primos por medio de la Criba de Eratóstenes pero cuando corro el programa no obtengo nada solo "[Z@677327b6"
podría alguien corregirme/ayudarme/decirme que está mal en mi código para al final poder ver el array completo con true y false? Gracias

```
public class NumerosPrimos {

    public static boolean[] primes(int n){
        boolean primos[] = new boolean[n+1];
        for (int i=2; i<=n; i++){
            primos[i]=true;     
        }
        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
            if(primos[i]){
                for(int j=i; i*j <= n; j++){
                    primos[i*j]=false;
                }
            }           
        }

        return primos;      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(primes(5));

    }
}
```

Comment: Como haces para saber si el numero es o no primo?

Comment: Estas imprimiendo magicamente un array de valores booleanos? que esperas recibir, y que esperas imprimir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu método para calcular los valores obtenidos por medio del algoritmo de ["Criba de Eratóstenes"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes) es correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que esta sucediendo es que estas imprimiendo el array de valores boolean, por esa razón se imprime:  "[Z@677327b6"

te aconsejo agregar otro método para imprimirlos, por ejemplo este método recibe el arreglo e imprime el valor de los elementos:

```
 public static void imprimePrimos(boolean[] primos){
     for(int i=0; i < primos.length; i++){
              System.out.println("Valor " +i + ": " + primos[i]);
        }                  
 }
```

y llamarlo de esta forma, suponiendo imprimir los primeros 20 valores:

```
imprimePrimos(primes(20));
```

de esta forma obtendrías la impresión de los valores en la consola:

```
Valor 0: false
Valor 1: false
Valor 2: true
Valor 3: true
Valor 4: false
Valor 5: true
Valor 6: false
Valor 7: true
Valor 8: false
Valor 9: false
Valor 10: false
Valor 11: true
Valor 12: false
Valor 13: true
Valor 14: false
Valor 15: false
Valor 16: false
Valor 17: true
Valor 18: false
Valor 19: true
Valor 20: false
```

---